# I want only 3 users can be simultaneously run my software

Tags: c#, licensing

I want just 3 users can be simultaneous Run my software.
My Software is written in c#.
Any idea, how to do the same?

Comment: 3 users means what??
3 users on network or in single pc ?

Comment: 3 Users on Network     , Users copy short cut from exe file from network on desktop and then run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in log-file all starts and exits (user, start date, exit date). When program start - check starts count and exits count. Maybe you should define old starts without exit as with exit (connection error and program can't write to log about her exit etc.).

Answer (score 0):

3 Users on Network , Users copy short cut from exe file from network on desktop and then run

Comment: i can give some suggestion right now and give code later if possible..
on load event of application, retrieve all network computer pc, now access their process and put a one counter variable, if it is 3, then message to user that already 3 users run this app else run that exe for user